# Java JDBC: Cannot connect to SQL due to unknown database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

So I've been able to connect to MySQL through Netbeans on my older computer, using the following code:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tblpizza?user=root"; 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"root","root");
```

However, since getting a new computer, every time I try to run the code, it comes up with this error:

> SQL Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   database 'root'

Being fairly new to coding in general, I tried researching different queries online but couldn't come up with a solution.

**Notes:**

-I tried changing different sections of my code, making sure I didn't miss any upper case/lower case letters

-I went onto MYSQL and ran a command to check all the database names, and made sure to copy the right one down

-No matter how I change the code in anyway, it always says "unknown database 'root'" even though I haven't put root down as the database name

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove `?user=root`. You are specifying the user in the `getConnection()` call.

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2006.

Answer (score 0):

Your database URL should not have the `?user=root` suffix.

Make it look like so, as you are specifying the username/password already in the `getConnection(url, username, password)` call.

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tblpizza";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this -only removing the ?user=root  - however it still comes up with the same error. I have not changed the getConnection() line either.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is asking from username and password in next step while making `con` object you should not specify it in connection `url`.
Try to run code by removing the `?user=root` from your connection `url`.

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tblpizza";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tblpizza","root","root");
```

Try this way, you can omit the connectionUrl variable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Comes up with the exact same output